In my Flutter Application when I upload a video recorded from camera or record the video inside the application it displays as rotated
In my Flutter Application when I upload a video recorded from camera or record the video inside the application it displays as rotated but on the other side the video downloaded from any source or picked from gallery (other than recorded videos) they are showing perfectly fine.
Kindly Help me with this
I've tried flutter_exif_rotation but it crashed my application when i use it
